# How to use finished GAN model with trianed weights to create new images?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am following [Jeff Heaton's tutorial](https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/t81_558_class_07_2_Keras_gan.ipynb) how to create a GAN with keras. Everything works fine even with my own dataset. However, I cannot figure out how to create a single new images. (Mr. Heaton creates 28 images in form of a collages!)

What I tried without success:

```
new_fixed_seed = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, 100))
generated_images = generator.predict(new_fixed_seed)
im = Image.fromarray(generated_images)
```

Result: `TypeError: Cannot handle this data type`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you debug the code? What is the size of the generated images? Why you do not try to store them with OpenCV? In which line you have the issue?

Comment: I guess Image.fromarray converts one array to image, but you have several images.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, for me when I calculate `generated images` I am using the following code for storing them locally:

```
# combine a squared number of images.
def combine_images(generated_images):

  generated_images =  np.transpose(generated_images , (0, 3, 1, 2))

  num = generated_images.shape[0]
  width = int(math.sqrt(num))
  height = int(math.ceil(float(num)/width))
  shape = generated_images.shape[2:]
  image = np.zeros((3,(height+3)*shape[0], (width+3)*shape[1]),
                 dtype=generated_images.dtype)

  for index, img in enumerate(generated_images):

    new_shape = (img.shape[0], img.shape[1]+ 4, img.shape[2] + 4)
    img_ = np.zeros(new_shape)
    img_[:, 2:  2+img.shape[1], 2:  2+img.shape[2]] = img

    i = int(index/width)
    j = index % width
    image[:, i*new_shape[1]: (i+1)*new_shape[1], j*new_shape[2]: (j+1)*new_shape[2]] = img_[:, :, :]
  return image

# store combined images
def store_image_maps(images_db, filename):
  image = combine_images(images_db)
  image = image * 127.5 + 127.5
  image = np.swapaxes(image, 0, 1)
  image = np.swapaxes(image, 1, 2)
  cv2.imwrite(filename,image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but I am not completely satisfied with it as I think it could be cleaner and I think there are unnecessary steps involved:

```
# SEED_SIZE is 100
fixed_seed = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, SEED_SIZE))

# used 64x64 because those were my image sizes
image_array = np.full((   
      64,64, 3),           
      255, dtype=np.uint8)

generated_images = generator.predict(fixed_seed)

#if you don't use 255 here the images are black
image_array[:] = generated_images * 255  

im = Image.fromarray(image_array)

im.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/test.png')
```